# Eclipse Kura Installation

Tags: eclipse, kura

I'm trying to install eclipse kura with eclipse committers . But when I'm giving below link :

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eclipse/kura/develop/kura/setups/kura.setup
```

It is saying that **The Project 'Eclipse kura' is already contained in the inedex .**

So, when I'm selecting the Eclipse Kura option from the list of index it is giving me below error :

> ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository code=1002 Unable to
>   read repository at
>   http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/201612211000.
>   org.tukaani.xz.XZFormatException: Input is not in the XZ format   at
>   org.tukaani.xz.common.DecoderUtil.decodeStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
>   at org.tukaani.xz.SingleXZInputStream.initialize(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.tukaani.xz.SingleXZInputStream.initialize(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.tukaani.xz.SingleXZInputStream.(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.tukaani.xz.XZInputStream.(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.tukaani.xz.XZInputStream.(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.XZedSimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(XZedSimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:80)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:57)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:768)
>   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)   at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.util.ReflectUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectUtil.java:116) 
>   at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:370)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:177)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager$Metadata.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:437)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:92)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$RepositoryLoader$Worker.perform(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:1625)
>   at org.eclipse.oomph.util.WorkerPool$Worker.run(WorkerPool.java:416)
>   at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need anymore to manually add the setup to the installer it is comes with the Eclipse index already.

As for error around "Input is not in the XZ format", I can only guess that there is some temporary download error as currently Neon.3 is being rolled out.

As stupid as it sounds, I would re-try after a while.